# Reset autorotation in Xcode after force landscape orientation in one view controller (swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rotation, device-orientation

An app in which I've begun to work supports all device orientations, except on of the views, which is landscape.

To force this orientation, I set the lanscape orientation value via AppDelegate:

*AppDelegate.swift*

```
var shouldSupportAllOrientation = true
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if (shouldSupportAllOrientation == true){
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
}
```

*ViewController.swift*

```
let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appdelegate.shouldSupportAllOrientation = false
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

But when the app navigates to other view controller, and the device is in portrait orientation (physically), views appear on landscape mode until device is rotated.

Is there a way to detect the 'real device orientation'?

Thank you

Comment: did you mean UIDeviceOrientation by "real device orientation"?

Comment: I mean the orientation the device is hold, not the orientation the view controller shows. This is because if I force the landscape orientation an I put the device in portrait mode, the view controller appears in landscape mode (because I force this orientation), but if from this situation I navigate back, the device orientation (still portrait) differs from view controller (remains landscape, when I set allOrientations to true). I don't know if I've explained the issue very well.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue.
After forcing the `UIDevice.current.orientation`, it seems that device can't update it anymore (which looks expected since it's a get-only property and represents physical orientation)

Try override supportedInterfaceOrientations in ViewController.swift:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .landscape
}
```

After that if you open this VC, the `interfaceOrientation` is landscape, but `UIDevice.current.orientation` is the real one. 
Just a note: you might want to flip width and height of your view if you work with frames and bounds.